# Placing Link Text Within a Button in Angular App

Tags: css, angular

I have an href link that triggers a download located within a button in my Angular component HTML. I can see both the button and the highlighted text link in my browser. However, when I click the link, nothing happens - in terms of triggering the download. This is what I have:

```
<button class="email-prompt-button" md-button>
    <a [href]="fileUrl" download="file.txt" class="btn-link">Download File</a>
</button>
```

Now, if I remove the button, and just have the `a` tag, it works:

```
<a [href]="fileUrl" download="file.txt" class="btn-link">Download File</a>
```

How can I get this to works as link text within a button?

Comment: Buttons can't contain links...it's invalid HTML. Pick on or the other.

Comment: Is there a way I can mimic a button-like appearance then?

Comment: You can probably just put your button class and md-button directive on the anchor tag.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you shape your anchor tag shapes to look like a button by applying custom css

or

If you're using Bootstrap you can apply below classes:

```
btn btn-primary
```

Just like

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a [href]="fileUrl" download="file.txt" class="btn btn-primary btn-link">Download File</a>
```

Comment: have a nice day Adarsh